# Is China's policy of phasing out foreign hardware and software against WTO rules?

Tags: international, china

> China's Communist Party has ordered all state offices to remove
> foreign hardware and software within three years, the Financial Times
> reported, in a move which could hit major U.S. firms including
> Microsoft, Dell and HP.
>
> The policy has been dubbed "3-5-2" because the replacement of the
> technology will happen at a pace of 30% in 2020, 50% in 2021, and 20%
> in 2022, the newspaper said, citing a note from brokerage firm China
> Securities. Analysts there estimate that 20 million to 30 million
> pieces of foreign equipment need to be replaced in China.

https://www.cnbc.com/2019/12/09/china-reportedly-orders-state-offices-to-remove-foreign-tech.html

Is China's phasing out of foreign tech against WTO laws? I remember that there's a WTO rule that states that the government cannot give preferential treatment to local companies when contracting private companies, so in this case removing foreign hardware and software would prevent foreign companies from acquiring contracts from the government and thus can it be said that this policy contravenes WTO rules?

Comment: Hasnt the US and its allies been doing the same for years, citing “national security”?  Eg 5G tech.